# Lock a file open through FTP?

Tags: linux, ftp, filelock

I'd like to lock files that are open through FTP, so once a file is being edited (on a mounted FTP folder in OSX) no one else can:
- save it (necessary)
- open it (optional)

Does anyone have any tips on how to accomplish this? I understand it might be tricking as when you open a file it just copies it locally and then re-uploads.

Comment: The FTP protocol offers no facility for this, so the short answer is: no you can't.

Comment: This would most definitely take a custom FTPD, or at least an FTPD that supports some sort of scripting system whereby you can implement suitable additional commands or scripts that run pre-RETR and post-STOR  to the lock the files. This could raise plenty of additional problems.

Comment: Does the file need to continue to be readable on the server after it has been retrieved for editing? You could retrieve then delete it, and just re-upload it when done. Essentially blocking double editing at the expense of the file being unavailable.

Comment: Hi guys, hmm yeah I was hoping to avoid anything that could raise more complications than I'm already dealing with :-D I think I'd need the file to still be available on the server, as some people may copy it down to view but without needing to make amendments.

Comment: You might consider switching from ftp to webdav via http.